# Member 'xyz' was not initialized in this constructor warning in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I have a following class:

```
class OneWireSensor : public Sensor {
private:
    float lastTemperatureValue;
    float lastHumidityValue;
public:
    OneWireSensor(PinData *pinData);
    float getLastTempVal(void);
    float getLastHumidVal(void);
};
```

The class's constructor:

```
OneWireSensor::OneWireSensor(PinData *pinData) : lastTemperatureValue(0.0F), lastHumidityValue(0.0F) {
    auto oneWireDriver = std::make_unique<OneWireDriver>(pinData);
    this->driver = std::move(oneWireDriver);
    this->lastTemperatureValue = 0.0f;
    this->lastHumidityValue = 0.0f;
}
```

And still I get two warnings:

```
Member 'lastHumidityValue' was not initialized in this constructor Code Analysis Problem
Member 'lastTemperatureValue' was not initialized in this constructor Code Analysis Problem
```

I explicitly assign values of those variables in the constructor's initialization list. Even assigning them once again in the constructor body does not help. I've read similar questions but the solutions still give me following warnings. My C complier's version is gnu-C11 and C++ compiler's: gnu-C++14.

What might be the case here?

**EDIT:** definition of Sensor abstract class:

```
class Sensor {
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<GenericDriver> driver;
public:
    Sensor() {};
    virtual void startNewReadout(void) = 0;
};
```

Creating OneWireSensor objects:

```
PinData sensor1Data = {GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4};
OneWireSensor tempSensor1(&sensor1Data);
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `Sensor`?

Comment: And can you show us the code where you instantiate this class?

Comment: Maybe you are calling the default constructor by mistake?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I edited the code to show the appropriate parts

Comment: @Roy2511 I believe not, since I am explicitly passing the parameters to that OneWireSensor(PinData *pinData), and besides, the warning is pointing at this particular constructor

Comment: Why are you (correctly) initializing the member variables in the constructors member initializer list and then assign values to the same members in the constructor body?

Comment: @TedLyngmo it was just a try to let this warning go. But it didn't help anyway

Comment: It looks like an issue with code analyzer. Your constructor correctly initializes members (except that creating `std::unique_ptr` with a pointer not created with `new` is a Very Bad Idea™)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks, I changed the Very Bad line to `std::unique_ptr<OneWireDriver> oneWireDriver(new OneWireDriver(pinData));` Coming back to the warnings, I guess I should just live with that

Comment: @Yksisarvinen he doesn't use any code analyzer he just compiles using some version of gcc. IMO problem is project configuration or other error which is not presented here (possibly old version of file is compiled). [mcve] is needed.

Comment: You should initialize `driver` in the member initializer list too:
`driver(std::make_unique<OneWireDriver>(pinData))`

Comment: Apparently there was something with the code analyzer. Thanks for pointing this out. @TedLyngmo what would be the advantage from that? I assign the value of `driver` below in the constructor, it does not give any warning and it works in the program

Comment: It has the same advantage as for the other members: you skip the step of default constructing first and then assigning a value.

Comment: @Slighten if you use some code analyzer please state this clearly in question, specify tool name and its version.